# Ubuntu fail to boot; trying to reinstall; cannot see option to reinstall with USB installer

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb

The Ubuntu on my laptop refuse to boot. After GRUB (assuming that's what the select boot menu is called) it only shows blank screen and either a flashing box in the up right corner 'wi fi is ready' or some error message in up left corner.

So, I want to try reinstall ubuntu. Per the advice here http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/how-to-reinstall-linux-1301262 I use https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ to create USB ubuntu (previously use DVD image, lost it). I plugged the created USB installer, started the laptop, GRUB show up, no option to boot from USB that I can see. Pressed F2/F12 in vain.

Help?

My laptop use dual OS with windows BTW. The Windows boot normally.

Perhaps I created to the USB installer wrong? Anyway to check it works right? Something else?

EDIT: Problem solved. I have managed to access BIOS and override boot from there. Though as it turns I don't need it anyway, because the old installation managed to got fix through some fiddling in recovery mode.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? What version of Windows? Have you tried other installers or other flash drives. Sometimes just a change seems to work. Did you verify ISO was downloaded correctly? IF new UEFI system you may have to turn on allow USB boot in UEFI settings. Download latest: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the differences between UEFI and BIOS. WIndows 7. That's the only flashdrive I have available at the moment. it is freshly purchased. I'm going to see if I can find the DVD installer later. Or burn a new one. Ah, no I haven't. I'll check that one now. How do one access UEFI settings? The Ubuntu version is already the latest download.

Comment: What version of Windows? If an older system then it it BIOS, most Windows 7 systems. UEFI is the new replacement for BIOS and is the standard required by Microsoft for all new computers since Windows 8 released October 26, 2012. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: Windows 7. BIOS it is then.

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to get into BIOS. I got this https://imgur.com/0BB5poN which explain why it won't boot. I try create new boot option https://imgur.com/PfIH8ba but I don't know how to fill the 'path for boot option' part.

Comment: You have an UEFI system, but if you installed Windows 7 using DVD have installed in CSM/BIOS/Legacy mode. In BIOS mode you only boot from MBR, if multiple drives you should be able to choose each drive if it has a boot loader. But path for boot option is UEFI as it wants /EFI/ubuntu or /EFI/Microsoft for UEFI boot files from ESP - efi system partition. UEFI & BIOS are totally different and not really compatible. Once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch, or grub will only boot other installs that are in same boot mode.